# how to get all results when no parameter is passed in the request url

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

i am making the request  : http://localhost:3000/getAll?warranty=1&model=M4 , it is showing all details with warranty=1 and model=M4 , but if i request http://localhost:3000/getAll?warranty=1 it is showing no results.

my request router is below

```
 router.get('/getAll', function(req, res, next) {
 var post = new Post(req.query);
  Post.find({connectivity:'hdmi1',warranty:post.warranty,model:post.model}).exec(f    unction(err, posts){
if(err){ return next(err); }
res.json(posts);
  });
  });
```

i want to get all results in case no model is specified in the query , please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is little point trying to cast your query data as a mongoose document just for the purpose of a query using `.find()`, as mostly mongoose will autocast types according to the defined schema anyway.

The basic case is to contruct the query dynamically, rather than code fixed positions:

```js
router.get('/getAll', function(req, res, next) {
   var query = { connectivity:'hdmi1' };
   /*
   // Or if you don't want the hardcoded value with no arguments
   var query = {};
   if ( req.query != 'undefined' )
       query = { connectivity:'hdmi1' };
   */
   for ( k in req.query ) {
       query[k] = req.query[k];
   }

   console.log(query);

   Post.find(query).exec(function(err, posts){
       if(err){ return next(err); }
       res.json(posts);
   });
});
```

So aside from the basic `connectivity` value you have hardcoded, the other paramters are only added to the query sent to the server where they are present.

It's generally not a wise idea to cast to a document like you are doing. There could be default values on the created object that would result in a generated query for values you really don't want. If anything then any generated query for non-existant fields with non-existant values should return a "not found" when the `posts` response is in fact empty or `null`.

It's also probably better to use `req.params` rather than `req.query` as a compatibility point, or if the method of argument submission changes.

Comment: thanks very much , will check this req.params also , also you have written console.log , but the logs are not getting printed there , i am using chrome.

Comment: @HimanshuKhandelwal The only purpose of `console.log()` is as an example of showing you how the query is contructed from the parameters given. Whatever your logging mechanism, it's a good practice to at least include something like this at a debug logging level.

Comment: sure..noted. Thanks again.